# Single row in ag-grid using autoHeight has extra space after row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid in an angular project and I'd like to use autoHeight. When there is only one row in the grid, there is space below the row inside the grid.
[grid with single row and extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H81CL.png)

When a second row is added, autoHeight works fine and does not display the extra space.
[grid with two rows and no extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcwmj.png)

I can remove the space by manually setting the height when there is a single row

```
this.systemOptions.length === 1 ? this.gridApi.setDomLayout() : this.gridApi.setDomLayout('autoHeight');
```

but I would prefer to use autoHeight for any number of rows. Is there a way to display a single row using autoHeight without the extra space below the row?

Comment: did you try messing with the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the documentation says, but I have altered the code from `unset` to `40` as this worked for me and it really looks weird without min-height.

> When using Auto Height, there is a minimum of 150px set to the grid
> rows section. This is to avoid an empty grid which would look weird.
> To remove this minimum height, add the following CSS:

```
.ag-center-cols-clipper {
    min-height: 40 !important;
}
```

Source:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-size/